# Why is Louvain Method Non-Deterministic?

Tags: graph-theory, igraph

I am using the implementation of the Louvain algorithm for community detection in igraph in R. I observe that running it multiple times produces different answers. However, when I read the algorithm
[Louvain Method - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louvain_method), nothing has any obvious randomness in it. My guess is that going through the points in different orders may produce different answers and that the igraph code randomizes the order of the vertices before processing them.  Is that why it produces multiple answers - or is there something else going on?

Comment: I only know of igraph for `R`, and I think I have used igraph for Python maybe two or three times in the last 7 or more years. So, asking from a position of substantial ignorance about this tool, is it possible to set a seed to control any randomness that hypothetically could exist in the implementation? I would think that if setting such a seed also fixes the output, then a random number generator is involved in the implementation somehow.

Comment: Yes,  setting the seed does give consistent output.  But I am more concerned with why this happens.  When I run this with different random seeds, I get really different community structures. This makes me question that any of these community structures reflect the underlying structure.

Comment: Thank you for checking that. My suggestion at this juncture is to [raise an issue](https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues) with the maintainers. They are the most likely to be the most familiar with the implementation details.

Comment: Thanks @Galen!!

Comment: I've used the python implementation of the Louvain community detection algorithm, as part of networkx. Here is a [networkx issue](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/6655) asking the same question; hopefully this helps. And the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.0476) mentions a step where ties (in modularity gain) are broken using a "rule" which might be related to the randomness as well.

Comment: @dipetkov  Very helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic algorithm processes vertices in order. But why should the storage order of vertices—merely a technical detail of the graph representation—be given a preference? igraph processes vertices in a random order to eliminate bias.

> When I run this with different random seeds, I get really different community structures. This makes me question that any of these community structures reflect the underlying structure.

This is precisely the main advantage of randomized methods. If we run the algorithm several times, and get completely different community structures, then you we that the result is meaningless. If we get comparable results between different runs, then we can be more confident about the result. Deterministic algorithms do not make it possible to check whether the result is meaningful in similar ways.

Comment: I am not sure whether 'meaningless' is the right choice.

Comment: Maybe 'inaccurate' or 'unstable' might be better.